# CSS3 curving effect

Tags: css, curve

I wonder if anyone can tell me if the curving effect shown in the image below is possible with CSS3.

[image]

If it is, how can I achieve it?

Comment: It is not super clear if you are asking about how to make that green curving line at the background or about how the images are positioned along that curve. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, the curve I was referring to is the curve of the images not the green background

Comment: The simplest way would be to position each one absolutely, if you fancy getting javascript involved, a very simple script would get you where you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be done:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/Bfwpz/

HTML:

```
<div id="boxWrap">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div>
    <div class="box5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxWrap { float: left;}

#boxWrap div {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.box1 { top: 20px; }
.box2 { top: -20px; }
.box3 { top: -50px; }
.box4 { top: -20px; }
.box5 { top: 20px; }
```